# Modify MediaWiki password changing message

Tags: mediawiki

I've installed Strong Password Extension for MediaWiki. However, in password changing page, when enter weak password, it just shows:

> Your password is invalid or too short. It must have at least 6 characters and be different from your username.

I want to give the strong password rules in the message. Where can I modify the message? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you did a string search for that message over all the files and still couldn't find it?

Comment: Thanks, found in ./languages/messages/MessagesEn.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also modify the System Message page MediaWiki:Passwordtooshort